# Find whole word that starts at character position in R

Tags: r

```
Str <- "I love chocolate pudding"
pos <- 8
```

I need to return the word that starts with the letter c at pos 8, which is chocolate. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring` to get everything after 8th character. Then remove everything after space using `gsub` :

```
gsub(" .*", "", substring(Str, pos))
```

In case you need to check for the "c":

```
Str <- "I love dogs"

ifelse(
  substr(Str, pos, pos) == "c",
  gsub(" .*", "", substring(Str, pos)),
  ""
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(Str, "(?<=[\\w\\s]{7})\\bc\\w+\\b")
[1] "chocolate"
```

This solution uses `str_extract` and positive lookbehind `(?<=[\\w\\s]{7})`, which can be glossed along these lines: "if you see seven characters consisting of alphanumeric characters (`\\w`) or white space (`\\s`) to the left, match the immediately next 'word' identified by its boundaries to either side (`\\b`) as well as the letter `c` occurring as the first letter of the word.

Alternatively, use `sub` and backreference:

```
sub(".{7}(\\bc\\w+\\b).*", "\\1", Str)
[1] "chocolate"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr` and ignoring the 'starting with 'c' condition:

```r
Str %>%
  str_sub(pos) %>%
  word(1)
```